# Create query statement to output records within a ROLLING time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, intervals

[image][image]What I am attempting to do is create a SELECT statement searching for duplicate cell values within a rolling 30 minute window. From a table that records every alert sent out to the DBA team.

Here is what I have.

```
USE db
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @AlertDateTime smalldatetime

SELECT  @AlertDateTime = getdate() 

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM SendAlertLog

WHERE EXISTS

(
    SELECT SendAlertLog.Event 

    FROM SendAlertLog

    GROUP BY Event  

    HAVING COUNT (1) >= 2
)

AND SendAlertLog.SkipFlag   != 'Y' 
AND AlertDateTime >= dateadd (mi, -30, @AlertDateTime) 

END
```

My results are a blank table with all the column headers.But there is over 95,000rows!

[Blank Table results from at table of 95,000rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8oRD.png)

Any suggestions on how to output alerts that occurred within the last 30 minutes?

[image: Proof of Alerts populating table: CST]

Image #2 shows last alert logged in the last 1min CST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @AlertDateTime DATETIME
SELECT @AlertDateTime = DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE())  

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.SendAlertLog
WHERE AlertDateTime >= @AlertDateTime 
    AND ISNULL(Skipflag, 'E') IN ('E', 'O', 'N')
```

Comment: Thank you but no luck. The table still returns blank. I even changed part of your query to include: 


WHERE AlertDateTime >= @AlertDateTime
AND Skipflag = 'E'
AND Skipflag = 'O'
AND Skipflag = 'N'
AND Skipflag = 'NULL'
AND Skipflag != 'Y'   I'm beginning to think this is not possible. I have been on this for 2days!

Comment: Sorry, but your condition is inconsistent. Please try updated answer.

Comment: Are you kidding? You saved me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Among many issues, is `SkipFlag` nullable?

```
AND SendAlertLog.SkipFlag != 'Y'
```

Since `null != 'Y'` is not true (but unknown), this will filter out all rows where `SkipFlag` is `null` or `'Y'`.

Comment: Devart included a great tip on how to include NULLS in a query output. Please look up ISNULL functions. Thanks!